# Assign values from a vector to the `call` attribute in a list of lm models (mapply?)

Tags: r, vectorization, mapply

I am working with a list of `lm` models. Let's create a small example of that:

```
set.seed(1234)
mydata <- matrix(rnorm(40),ncol=4)

modlist <- list()

for (i in 1:3) {
  modlist[[i]] <- lm(mydata[,1] ~ mydata[,i+1])
}
```

In reality there about 50 models. If you print the `modlist` object, you'll notice that the `call` attribute for each model is generic, namely `lm(formula = mydata[, 1] ~ mydata[, i + 1])`. As later subsets of this list will be needed, I would like to have the convenience to see the name of the dependent variable in each model, assigning that name to the respective `call` attribute:

```
modlist[[1]]$call <- "Factor 1"
```

One can see that the model call has changed to "Factor 1" in the first element of `modlist`.  Let us say I have a vector of names, which I would like to assign:

```
modnames <- paste0("Factor",1:3)
```

It would be, of course, possible to assign the respective value of that vector to the respective model in the list, e.g.:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  modlist[[i]]$call <- modnames[i]
}
```

Is there a vectorized version of this? I suspect it will be `mapply`, but I can't figure out how to combine the assignment operator with extracting the respective element of the list, i.e. `[[()`. More of a purist anti-loop premature optimization exercise, but still :) Thank you!